# Check if directory exists, but string is relative path

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am currently writing a program to check if hyperlinks in a file are broken.  Some hyperlinks go directly to folders on a mapped drive.

I want to use `dir()` to check if the folder exists, but Excel shortens the string to the relative version `"../../Random folder/Another random folder"`

This string returns `""` so my function thinks the folder does not exist, but it does and its link functions properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the overloaded function of Dir and specify vbDirectory as the additional argument. I believe it should look something like this:
    If Dir("X:\random directory\other random directory", vbDirectory) = "" Then

Comment: Mifo,

Thanks for pointing that out.  That was a very obvious fix. :/

Comment: For some reason I am unable to get both dir() and the file system object approach to work.  This is really baffling.  The directories are mapped using UNC paths.  Is that the issue?  My code works so long as the file is on my local hard drive.  Once I get on the network it no longer works.